# Clinical decision tree using R

Tags: r

I'm trying to code [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eb5Q.png) decision tree using R. I was wondering if there was a better way to go about this rather than using a ton of conditionals?

```
# ops
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
options(warn=-1)
saveFiles = FALSE
setwd("~/Documents/Education/UCLA/Spring 2016/MGMT271B/proj/")

# data vars
n = 10
T = c("X", seq(0,4), "is") 
N = c("X", seq(0,3)) 
M = c("X", seq(0,1)) 
S = c("1A", "1B", "2A", "2B", "3A", "3B", "3C", "4")
h = c("ductal", "lobular", "mixed", "metaplastic", "tubular", "mucinous")

# necessary functions
create_data <- function(n) {
  return (data.frame(PatientID       = sample(10^12, n, FALSE), 
                     Histology       = sample(h, n, TRUE), 
                     ER              = factor(sample(c("TRUE", "FALSE"), n, TRUE)),
                     PR              = factor(sample(c("TRUE", "FALSE"), n, TRUE)),
                     HER2            = factor(sample(c("TRUE", "FALSE"), n, TRUE)),
                     PrimaryTumor    = factor(paste0("T", sample(T, n, TRUE))),
                     TumorSize       = round(runif(n, 0, 6),2), 
                     NearbyLymphNode = paste0("N", sample(N, n, TRUE)), 
                     Metastasis      = paste0("M", sample(M, n, TRUE)), 
                     Stage           = sample(S, n, TRUE), row.names=NULL))
}

get_patient_data <- function(df, id) {
  return (df[df$PatientID == id,])
}

get_treatment_rec <- function(Histology, ER, PR, HER2, PrimaryTumor, TumorSize, NearbyLymphNode, Metastasis, Stage) {
  if (Histology %in% c("ductal", "lobular", "mixed", "metaplastic")) {
    if (ER == TRUE || PR == TRUE) {
      if (HER2 == TRUE) {
        if (NearbyLymphNode %in% c("N0", "N1") & PrimaryTumor %in% c("T1", "T2", "T3")){
          if (TumorSize <= 0.5) { 
            if (NearbyLymphNode == "N0") {
              message(cat("Consider adjuvant endocrine therapy and/or adjuvant chemotherapy with Trastuzumab"))
            }
            if (NearbyLymphNode == "N1") {
              message(cat("Adjuvant endocrine therapy or adjuvant chemotherapy with Trastuzumab followed by endocrine therapy"))
            }
          } else if (TumorSize > 0.06 & TumorSize < 1.0) {
            message(cat("Adjuvant endocrine therapy and/or adjuvant chemotherapy with Trastuzumab"))
          } else {
            message(cat("Adjuvant endocrine therapy and adjuvant chemotherapy with Trastuzumab"))
          }
        }
      } else if (HER2 == FALSE) {
        if (NearbyLymphNode %in% c("N0", "N1") & PrimaryTumor %in% c("T1", "T2", "T3")) {
          if (TumorSize <= 0.5){
            if (NearbyLymphNode == "N0") {
              message(cat("Consider adjuvant endocrine therapy"))
            }
            if (NearbyLymphNode == "N1") {
              message(cat("Adjuvant endocrine therapy and/or adjuvant chemotherapy"))
            }
          } else {
            message(cat("Consider 21-gene RT-PCR assay"))
          }
        }
      } 
    } else if (ER == FALSE & PR == FALSE) {
      if (HER2 == TRUE) {
        if (NearbyLymphNode %in% c("N0", "N1") & PrimaryTumor %in% c("T1", "T2", "T3")) {
          if (TumorSize <= 0.5) {
            if (NearbyLymphNode == "N0") {
              message(cat("Consider adjuvant chemotherapy with Trastuzumab"))
            }
            if (NearbyLymphNode == "N1") {
              message(cat("Consider adjuvant chemotherapy with Trastuzumab"))
            }
          } else if (TumorSize > 0.06 & TumorSize < 1.0) {
            message(cat("Consider adjuvant chemotherapy with Trastuzumab"))
          } else {
            message(cat("Adjuvant chemotherapy with Trastuzumab"))
          }
        }  
      } else if (HER2 == FALSE) {
        if (NearbyLymphNode %in% c("N0", "N1") & PrimaryTumor %in% c("T1", "T2", "T3")) {
          if (TumorSize <= 0.5) {
            if (NearbyLymphNode == "N0") {
              message(cat("No adjuvant therapy"))
            }
            if (NearbyLymphNode == "N1") {
              message(cat("Consider adjuvant chemotherapy"))
            }
          } else if (TumorSize > 0.06 & TumorSize < 1.0) {
            message(cat("Consider adjuvant chemotherapy"))
          } else {
            message(cat("Adjuvant chemotherapy"))
          }
        }  
      } else {
        message(cat("Invalid HER2 Status. Exiting."))
      }
    }
  } else if (Histology %in% c("tubular", "mucinous")) { 
    if (ER == TRUE || PR == TRUE) {
      if (NearbyLymphNode %in% c("N0", "N1") & PrimaryTumor %in% c("T1", "T2", "T3")) {
        if (TumorSize <= 1) {
          message(cat("No adjuvant therapy"))
        } else if (TumorSize > 1 & TumorSize < 3) {
          message(cat("Consider adjuvant endocrine therapy"))
        } else {
          message(cat("Adjuvant endocrine therapy"))
        }
      }
    } else if (ER == FALSE || PR == FALSE) {
      message(cat("Repeat determination of ER/PR status"))
    }
  } else {
    message(cat("Invalid Histology Status. Exiting"))
  }
}



# tests
n = 20 
data = create_data(n)
if(saveFiles){
  write.table(data, "data.tsv", sep="\t", col.names=NA)
  system("gzip data.tsv")  
}

get_patient_data(data, data$PatientID[1])
get_patient_data(data, "12857252013")
get_treatment_rec(Histology="ductal", ER=TRUE, PR=FALSE, HER2=TRUE, PrimaryTumor="T1", TumorSize=1.02, NearbyLymphNode="N1", Metastasis=NULL, Stage=NULL) 
get_treatment_rec(Histology="mucinous", ER=FALSE, PR=TRUE, HER2=TRUE, PrimaryTumor="T1", TumorSize=4.22, NearbyLymphNode="N0", Metastasis=NULL, Stage=NULL)
```

Comment: It looks pretty compact and straightforward to me.  However, I think you have a typo here: `TumorSize > 0.06`.  Should be `TumorSize > 0.6`.

Comment: Ah! Good catch!

Comment: Another choice for such an unbalanced tree would be a nested list.

Answer (score 2):

I think the common wisdom is to go data driven instead of hard coding
the tree.  Then again, it's not clear if that helps too much here.

Let me suggest a few other things first to make the code a bit more
compact.

- `message(cat(...))` is used very often, but it seems the `cat` isn't
  actually necessary here?  Also, since all the function
  `get_treatment_rec` does is to print/`message` the result, I'd say
  that just returning the string and calling `message` outside of it is
  far better in terms of composability,
  i.e. `message(get_treatment_rec(...))`.  Making use of the fact that R
  will just return the last value in the function, it becomes much more
  simple.  There are also quite a number of "empty" cases - shouldn't
  those also do something or at least return an error response?
- Use `&&` instead of `&` unless you really want to evaluate all
  arguments.  `&&` and `||` are much more common since they can do less
  work if the first parameter is already `FALSE` / `TRUE` respectively.
- `x == FALSE` is usually written as `!x` unless you really only want to
  match `FALSE` (not all "falsy" things).  Same goes for `x == TRUE`
  vs. just `x`.
- Don't write something like `if (foo) {} else if (!foo) {}` - that's
  unnecessary information as there's only two cases anyway, just use a
  regular `else` branch instead, i.e. `if (foo) {} else {}`.
- Now, there are recurring cases.  I'd put those either into a variable
  and only calculate them once (and name them), or put them into a
  function and reuse that.  Note that I have no idea what to name these,
  so I'm using the usual `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, ... here.

For posterity I'm going to paste the resulting function, but it's really
just for illustration purposes:

```
get_treatment_rec <- function(Histology, ER, PR, HER2, PrimaryTumor, TumorSize, NearbyLymphNode, Metastasis, Stage) {
  foo <- NearbyLymphNode %in% c("N0", "N1") && PrimaryTumor %in% c("T1", "T2", "T3")

  if (Histology %in% c("ductal", "lobular", "mixed", "metaplastic")) {
    if (ER || PR) {
      if (HER2) {
        if (foo) {
          if (TumorSize <= 0.5) {
            if (NearbyLymphNode == "N0") {
              "Consider adjuvant endocrine therapy and/or adjuvant chemotherapy with Trastuzumab"
            } else if (NearbyLymphNode == "N1") {
              "Adjuvant endocrine therapy or adjuvant chemotherapy with Trastuzumab followed by endocrine therapy"
            }
          } else if (TumorSize > 0.06 & TumorSize < 1.0) {
            "Adjuvant endocrine therapy and/or adjuvant chemotherapy with Trastuzumab"
          } else {
            "Adjuvant endocrine therapy and adjuvant chemotherapy with Trastuzumab"
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (foo) {
          if (TumorSize <= 0.5) {
            if (NearbyLymphNode == "N0") {
              "Consider adjuvant endocrine therapy"
            }
            if (NearbyLymphNode == "N1") {
              "Adjuvant endocrine therapy and/or adjuvant chemotherapy"
            }
          } else {
            "Consider 21-gene RT-PCR assay"
          }
        }
      }
    } else if (!ER && !PR) {
      if (HER2) {
        if (foo) {
          if (TumorSize <= 0.5) {
            if (NearbyLymphNode == "N0" || NearbyLymphNode == "N1") {
              "Consider adjuvant chemotherapy with Trastuzumab"
            }
          } else if (TumorSize > 0.06 & TumorSize < 1.0) {
            "Consider adjuvant chemotherapy with Trastuzumab"
          } else {
            "Adjuvant chemotherapy with Trastuzumab"
          }
        }
      } else if (!HER2) {
        if (foo) {
          if (TumorSize <= 0.5) {
            if (NearbyLymphNode == "N0") {
              "No adjuvant therapy"
            } else if (NearbyLymphNode == "N1") {
              "Consider adjuvant chemotherapy"
            }
          } else if (TumorSize > 0.06 & TumorSize < 1.0) {
            "Consider adjuvant chemotherapy"
          } else {
            "Adjuvant chemotherapy"
          }
        }
      } else {
        "Invalid HER2 Status. Exiting."
      }
    }
  } else if (Histology %in% c("tubular", "mucinous")) {
    if (ER || PR) {
      if (foo) {
        if (TumorSize <= 1) {
          "No adjuvant therapy"
        } else if (TumorSize > 1 && TumorSize < 3) {
          "Consider adjuvant endocrine therapy"
        } else {
          "Adjuvant endocrine therapy"
        }
      }
    } else if (!ER || !PR) {
      "Repeat determination of ER/PR status"
    }
  } else {
    "Invalid Histology Status. Exiting"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the best practices in R coding the maximum numbers of characters in line is 80. Then people who read your code don't have to scroll horizontally if you stick to the rule.

In R studio your can turn on the margin line.

Also you shouldn't write `return` at the end of the function.